# Android and drawing image

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to draw image in place  where I click. i have this code:

```
public class CanvasdrawActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView picture;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        picture=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_bez_nog);

        picture.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                int x = (int) event.getX() ;
                int y = (int) event.getY() ;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

How I can draw picture from resources in place where I click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Canvas, and canvas.drawBitmap( )